# Select columns based on prefix in a formula

Tags: r, dataframe

I am using R.

I have to write a formula of the form:
`y ~ a + b + c_1 + c_2 + c_3 + d + e | f | c_1 + c_2 + c_3`

What's the best way to select all the columns that start with `c_` when I have lots of them?

Those columns come from a dataframe, so `names(df)` retrieves all the possible variables

Comment: Do you want to select columns or do you want to get the right names as string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```r
vec <- names(df)[startsWith(names(df), "c_")]
```

and then for example use

```r
paste(vec, collapse = "+")
#> [1] "c1+c2+c3"
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use `reformulate`

```
vec <- grep("^c_", names(df), value = TRUE)
reformulate(vec)
~c1 + c2 + c3
```